# Separar página de login das outras páginas que são carregadas a partir do ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho uma pequena aplicação `SPA` (*Single Page Application*) com `AngularJS` onde todas as páginas são carregadas no `index.html` através do `ng-view`.

Porém eu adicionei um layout com uma barra lateral e mais algumas coisas nessa página e chamo o `ng-view` dentro desse layout. Dessa forma quando carrego a página de login esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de exibir apenas a página de login separada, o restante das páginas seriam inclusas nesse template.

Qual a melhor maneira de resolver esse problema?

**Index.html**

```
.../Trecho do navBar+sideBar

    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div ng-view></div>

            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Não coloquei todo código pois é um pouco grande, porém ja da pra ver onde o `ng-view` fica.

Essa é a config das rotas:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
  templateUrl: "src/views/home.html",
  controller: "loginCtrl"

});   
$routeProvider.when("/login", {
  templateUrl: "src/views/login.html",
  controller: "loginCtrl"

});
$routeProvider.otherwise({
  redirectTo: "/login"
});

});
```

Update:
script que funcionava antes e agora com nova solução não funciona mais:

```
<script>
  $(".menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });
  </script>
```

Botão que fica no `navBar` que agora está separado em outra página:

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed menu-toggle">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faço esse serviço utilizando o ui-router ao invés do ngRoute. Ele é mais robusto e tem um funcionamento melhor.

É uma ideia um tanto quanto complexa e você vai precisar adaptar isso ao seu modo de autenticação, que pode ser (e provavelmente será) diferente de muitos outros.

A resposta que vou lhe passar seria utilizando o [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), o que recomendo você olhar, pois ele é melhor que o `ngRoute`.

A ideia é que você possua uma view principal, que carregue o html correspondente, dependendo da autenticação ou não do usuário. E a view secundária que irá carregar o conteúdo do app.

```
<div ui-view="main"></div> //Irá carregar ou a página de login ou a página do app;
<div ui-view="auth"></div> //Irá carregar todo o app somente se o usuário autenticar;
```

A `div ui-view="main"` será na página index, então na página index você não acrescenta mais nenhum html, somente determinar qual view será carregada, a `login.html` ou a `autenticado.html`.

Já na `div ui-view="auth"` você irá carregar somente se passar a autenticação, então dentro dessa div você carregaria o html que roda todo o seu app, ex.: cliente.html, servico.html, etc...

Exemplo dos arquivos html:

#### index.html

```
<head>
   suas inicializações
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
</body>
```

#### Login.html

```
<form>
    ...
</form>
```

#### autenticado.html

```
<header>
    .. seu header ..
</header>
<nav>
    .. seu menu ..
</nav>
<div ui-view="auth"></div>
```

Repare que no arquivo autenticado.html ele possui outra `ui-view`, pois é somente nessa view que você irá carregar as páginas que necessitam de autenticação.

A configuração do router seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
//Se NÃO passar a autenticação, abre esse .state
.state('login', {
    url: "/BemVindo",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            templateUrl: "login.html"
        }
    }           
})
 //Se PASSAR a autenticação, abre esse .state
.state('autenticado', {
    url: "/Ola",
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'AutenticadoCtrl',
            templateUrl: "autenticado.html"
        }
    }
})
    //A partir de agora você teria multiplos .state para cada menu do seu app
    .state('cliente', {
        parent: 'autenticado',
        url: "/Clientes",
        views: {
            "auth": {
                controller: 'ClienteCtrl',
                templateUrl: "autenticado/cliente.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

Espero que eu tenha conseguido deixar a ideia geral clara para você montar o seu processo. Qualquer coisa me questione que eu tento ajudar o máximo que puder.

Comment: Esse main que vai dentro do ui-view é o que? uma página?

Comment: É só o nome da view. Repare que dentro da configuração da rota existe um campo `view: main` ou `view: auth`. É ali que eu 'escolho' em qual view aquele determinado template será exibido. Mas isso envolve uma estrutura de parent view e child view. Mas você encontra toda essa documentação no github do ui-router, se optar por usar ele.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar, já falo se funcionou. Obrigado

Comment: Opa, funcionou quase tudo, porém como faço pra chamar a url /Clientes? quando tento passar apenas /Clientes não funciona

Comment: Ela não funciona pois está vinculada ao state 'pai' dela, que seria `/BemVindo/Clientes`. Não cheguei a tentar isso, mas acredito que basta remover a `url:/BemVindo` (toda a linha) do state pai que resolve

Comment: Se eu removo a página de login não é mais exibida

Comment: Perdão, seria a linha url do state autenticado, que é ele que abre a porta para o seu app.

Comment: Entendi, coloquei /Ola/Clientes e funcionou, não tem problema fazer dessa forma não né?

Comment: Fica a seu critério. Eu até utilizo assim para dar um feedback sobre onde ele está. Por exemplo, sempre vai ser uma url assim adm/cliente ou adm/servico, etc..

Comment: Entendi, tranquilo. Uma ultima pergunta, eu tinha um script que eu deixava no final da página index.html onde tudo ficava junto, esse script fazia com que um button escondesse e mostrasse a sideBar. Porém agora não funciona, nem na página index e nem na autenticado, que é onde está o botão. Teria que colocar esse script em algum lugar especifico?

Comment: Se ele tiver dependência com algum controller ou coisa do tipo, teria que ver certinho se houve alguma alteração. Acredito que seja por isso.

Comment: Acho que ele não depende de nenhum controller, é um script bem pequeno vou editar a pergunta e colocar no final

Comment: pergunta editada

Comment: Olha, como ele já envolve jQuery, eu não saberia te dizer muito. Mas ele deveria funcionar com o script dentro do autenticado.html. Tanto o botao como o script. Talvez se você executar o script dentro de um `document.ready`, será?

Comment: Eu também não entendo muito, vou tentar resolver essa parte. Obrigado pela resposta que solucionou o meu problema.